# Both Xcode debug memory graph and Instruments can not detect leak in this case?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I did a small experiment: there are 2 view controllers:
In the first (root view controller) I put this code to present 2nd view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)

  present(ViewController2(), animated: true) {
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Here is the code inside ViewController2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
  var workItem: DispatchWorkItem?
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
      self.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
  }
  
  deinit {
    print("deinit called")
  }
}
```

Because in view controller 2, `self` hold a strong reference to `workItem` and `workItem` hold a strong reference to `self`, there should be a memory leak here: view controller 2 will not be released after we done presenting it (proof is the line `deinit called` is not printed and if I comment this statement `self.view.backgroundColor = .red`, it print out: `deinit called`)

But then when I try using `Xcode` `memory graph debug` and later `Instrument` to verify this leak, they both told me that there is no leak here.

Am I missing something?

Thanks everyone and have a nice day!

Comment: If you make the second view controller present on a button press, rather than in the viewDidAppear you can see in the [memory graph debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh2qV.png) that it will retain multiple copies of ViewController2, however in Instruments it doesn't seem to pick up the memory leak.

Comment: … and Instruments won’t find it because this is not a “leak”, per se. This is “abandoned” memory, not a “leak”. Instruments and Debug Memory Graph detect two completely different types of issues.

Comment: thanks for your answer folks. Can you elaborate on why this is `abandoned` memory? @rob

Comment: nice observation @Andrew

Comment: Understand the difference between `leaked` and `abandoned`. Let's say we use `button` as Andrew suggested above, there will be many instances of ViewController2 are created. How can I refer to them? If we don't have any reference to those instances, this should be memory leak? @Rob

Comment: checking it out, thanks @Rob